# Blacklist the "default.aspx" tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

There is 19 questions tagged with [default.aspx](/questions/tagged/default.aspx) at stackoverflow at the moment.

You could search `default.aspx` at https://stackoverflow.com/tags

[image]

but clicking the tag button does not work because of server side issues.

So, I think that tag should be blacklisted and probably rename it to [default-aspx](/questions/tagged/default-aspx) or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good solution would be to not allow periods in tag names. Period.

Comment: What about .NET, ASP.NET, VB.NET, ...?

Comment: @Justing good point. I had though that any substring after the period would be interpreted as a file extension, but apparently it is only true for `.aspx`. I guess the substring `.aspx` should be disallowed, then?

Comment: Many SE sites routinely use periods in tag names. AskUbuntu uses tags like `[10.10]` or `[11.04]` on most posts. Mathoverflow and cstheory both use periods to separate the category part of a tag from the rest (like `[ds.algorithms]` where `ds` stands for "data structures").

Comment: There is around 700+ valid tags with dots in the tag name in Stack Overflow, so it is not good to get rid of all dots. and there is .aspxauth tag, which looks valid. So, probably if they want to disallow those, only .aspx or ends with .aspx would be ok to remove.